# Spring security x509 tests are not working as I expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x509

I have a simple application doing *mutual TLS*. In practice, when running the app, everything works as I expect.

However this following **test** doesn't work and I would like to understand why, as it seems to go in the security chain but the *truststore* configuration seems to be completely ignored.

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebMvcTest
public class ConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }


    public void untrustedClientShouldBeForbidden() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/load")

        .with(x509(getCertificateFromFile("src/test/resources/untrusted-cert.pem")))
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()));
    }
```

The security configuration I have is very simple and is as follow:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //disable crsf and sessions for this web app
        http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
          .and().x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
```

And my test configuration (which works when doing manual testing) looks like this (application-test.properties):

```
server.ssl.trust-store=src/test/resources/test.truststore
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

EDIT: renamed the unit test function to better convey the intent of the test.

Comment: What do you mean by *However this following test doesn't work*? What response do you get?

Comment: When I run untrustedClientShouldBeForbidden() integration test I expect to be returned a 403 from the server however the unit tests runs with a 200. I expect the client call with an untrusted cert to be denied access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my test class was not properly annotated.

On my main configuration class I changed:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")})
@ComponentScan("foo.bar.blah")
public class Application {
```

To:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="foo.bar.blah")
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")})
public class Application {
```

And in my test class I stopped using **@MockWebMvc** in favor of this configuration:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ConfigurationTest {
```

Now the configuration is picked up properly and the unit tests all behave as I expected.

Comment: can you please provide the full unit test code somewhere ? I am kinda stuck on the same and nothing seems to be working